# how to add a marquee next prev button

Tags: html, css

trying to show some announcement to my visitors and I have been using for that `marquee` tag. I would like to ask if it was possible to add next prev `button` for `marquee` in case a user might not wait until it completely slides.

```
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="right">
<li>first message</li>
<li>second message</li>
<li>third message</li>
</marquee>
```

and if it was possible multiple `li` one after another

Answer (score 1):

```
<marquee>
```

> Non-standard
>
> This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not
>   use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every
>   user. There may also be large incompatibilities between
>   implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

Suggest to use alternatives like http://www.jquerynewsticker.com/ It has the controls that you asked.